# Get Enum type from value

Tags: c#, enums

```
public enum WeekDays { Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue=3, Wed=4, Thu=5, Fri=6, Sat=7 }
```

I have this enum, I have the value of the enum. what I want to do is by passing value get the type that I want to pass this to below function. I can do this by switch case any better ways??

for Example : value is 6 then Weekdays.Fri as a type should be passed to the below  function.

```
  public void CreateNew(WeekDays days)
  {
   //Some logic
  }
```

Comment: There's already an enum for this: [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)

Comment: yes @TimSchmelter it is a dummy code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is cast the value.

```
CreateNew((WeekDays)6);
```

enum values are essentially just typed integers, so you can freely cast both ways between enum and integral types. It's even possible to cast an integer value that doesn't exist in the enum into that type with no problem, so if you want to avoid that, remember to add validation that checks that the value exists before casting.

Answer (score 4):

Just cast value to enum:

```
CreateNew((WeekDays)value)
```

BTW usually it's nice to check if value is declared in enum, if source of value is not safe. Otherwise you can pass `(WeekDays)42`:

```
public void CreateNew(WeekDays days)
{  
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(WeekDays), days))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    // SomeLogic
}
```